# Why do I get "exception spec is more lax than base" error with this piece of code?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, libc++, noexcept

Trying to compile the following code using the clang version in Xcode 6.1 (clang-600.0.54 based on LLVM 3.5svn), with `-std=c++11` and `-stdlib=libc++` gives me some errors that I don't really understand.

```
#include <functional>

struct Impl
{
    typedef std::function<void ()> L;
    L l;
    int i;
};

struct Hndl
{
    Impl* impl;
    Hndl(Impl* i): impl(i) {}
    ~Hndl() noexcept(false) {}
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    Hndl h(new Impl());
    h.impl->l = [=]
    {
        h.impl->i = 42;
    };
    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
In file included from t.cpp:1:
/Applications/Xcode-6.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/functional:1293:52: error: exception specification of overriding
      function is more lax than base version
template<class _FD, class _Alloc, class _FB> class __func;
                                                   ^
/Applications/Xcode-6.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/functional:1593:13: note: in instantiation of template class
      'std::__1::__function::__func<<lambda at t.cpp:20:14>, std::__1::allocator<<lambda at t.cpp:20:14> >, void ()>' requested here
        if (sizeof(_FF) <= sizeof(__buf_) && is_nothrow_copy_constructible<_Fp>::value)
            ^
/Applications/Xcode-6.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/functional:1697:5: note: in instantiation of function template
      specialization 'std::__1::function<void ()>::function<<lambda at t.cpp:20:14> >' requested here
    function(_VSTD::forward<_Fp>(__f)).swap(*this);
    ^
t.cpp:20:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::function<void ()>::operator=<<lambda at t.cpp:20:14> >' requested here
        h.impl->l = [=]
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode-6.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/functional:1281:39: note: overridden virtual function is here
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY virtual ~__base() {}
                                      ^
1 error generated.
```

Looks as if `Impl::L::~L()` somehow inherits the `noexcept(false)` of `Hndl::~Hndl()`, but I don't know why. 
Interestingly the same code compiles if I comment out the assignment to `h.impl->i` inside the lambda. 
Also compiles if I remove the `noexcept(false)` specification from `Hndl::~Hndl()`, but I need that (would be a bit long to explain why, but I do). 
Also compiles if the lambda captures by ref, but the whole point here would be to be able to copy handles that share an implementation. 
Adding `noexcept(true)` to `Impl::~Impl()` doesn't help.

ideone.com's c++11 compiler happily compiles it as it is.

Could anyone explain me what's happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda captures `h`, which has a potentially-throwing destructor, so the lambda's closure type also has a potentially-throwing destructor.

With that in mind, you can reduce the problem to this:

```
#include <functional>

struct F
{
    void operator()() { }

    ~F() noexcept(false) {}
};

int main() {
    std::function<void ()> f = F{};
}
```

It seems that the `std::function` in libc++ cannot store a callable type without a nothrow destructor which looks like a bug in libc++.

From the error messages it looks as though the fix might be as simple as adding an explicit `noexcept` to the `__func` destructor, but I'm not familiar with the implementation so it might not be that easy.

I don't see any obvious workarounds except wrapping your `Hndl` type in another type with a `noexcept` destructor, so capturing it in the lambda does not make the lambda have a `noexcept(false)` destructor.  I tried something like this, but libc++ seems to have similar problems in `shared_ptr`:

```
    std::function<void ()> f = std::bind(&Hndl::operator(), std::make_shared<Hndl>());
```

Comment: Is this explicitly allowed in standard somewhere? [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/~function) reference states that `~function` has `noexpect` specifier, but it can be wrong (again).

Comment: `std::function` definitely has a `noexcept` destructor, but it should still be able to store types that don't. If your destructor doesn't actually throw  there is no problem and the program should work perfectly. If your destructor throws when stored in a `std::function` it would cause a call to `std::terminate()`

Comment: @imre  So the code is not guaranteed to work if destructor throws anyway. I don't see a reason to declare it `noexcept(false)` then.

Comment: @frymode, I disagree, it might throw in some situations but not in others, so  `noexcept(false)` is appropriate. If you happen to know that it will never throw when stored in a `std::function` then the `noexcept(false)` is also safe.

Comment: Agree, that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, as Jonathan said, in the actual code I have a branch in the destructor. It's kind of a recursive data structure, with its destructor handling the top-level differently. Non-top-level instances may throw, but those are handled; top-level instances never throw, and only top-level are capture in lambdas. So I could create two distinct classes for these two cases with diff dtor exception specs, or maybe create my own lightweight function-like lambda store. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `Hndl` is captured in lambda by value and `std::function` destructor is treated as `noexcept(true)` since it is not stated otherwise in it's definition. So `Hndl` instance cannot be safely destroyed in `l` destructor. As for why error disappears if member assignment is removed from lambda - most likely captured value is just optimized away by compiler.

Comment: The first part of your answer is right, the last sentence is not. The error disappears if you remove the assignment because then `h` doesn't get captured, so the exception-specification of `~Hndl()` has no relevance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible workaround, based on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/313312/Cplusplus-Lambda-Storage-Without-libcplusplus

Note that the below code is simplified for demonstration purposes; it is incomplete, and only handles void() lambdas. See the above link for the real thing (although in my particular case void() is enough).

```
#include <functional>

struct Lambda
{
    void* lambda;
    void (*execute)(void*);

    template <typename T> Lambda& operator=(T&& t)
    {
        lambda = new T(t);
        execute = [](void* lambda) { ((T*)lambda)->operator()(); };
        return *this;
    }

    void operator()() { execute(lambda); }
};

//  ---

struct Impl
{
    Lambda l;
    int i;
};

struct Hndl
{
    Impl* impl;
    Hndl(Impl* i): impl(i) {}
    ~Hndl() noexcept(false) {}
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    Hndl h(new Impl());
    h.impl->l = [=]
    {
        h.impl->i = 42;
    };

    h.impl->l();

    return 0;
}
```